# What is the song when Usopp is defeating Sugar by using his Haki?

Tags: one-piece, music

In *One Piece* episode 697, there's a song when Ussop is defeating Sugar using his Haki. It starts at 0:53 in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/LyyG9DXuBDM?t=53s).

What is this song? Is it already released as a soundtrack?

Comment: Did you look it up at http://onepiecetracklist.com/ ? Just type in the number of the episode.

Comment: Didn't even know such page would exist, it gave me the answers I was looking for. A lot of thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is "The Straw Hats Gather and Head to Battle!" from the album "New World", track #44.

According to the [OP's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46580/what-is-the-song-when-usopp-is-defeating-sugar-by-using-his-haki/46618#comment60859_46618),

> Ah, the song I was looking for was the one that sounds after that. And since it was answered, here it is: 
>   youtube.com/watch?v=TBKUNyxItyM

Comment: Ah, the song I was looking for was the one that sounds after that. And since it was answered, here it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBKUNyxItyM

Thanks for your reply.